# Load R packages only once when executing R scripts via bash

Tags: r, bash, rscript

I have an R file `example.r` which basically looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
# do something ...
library(somelibrary)
# do something with somelibrary functions
```

And a bash script which needs to call `Rscript example.r <PARAMETER>` multiple times with different input parameters during one execution. My question is whether there is way to load the package `somelibrary` only once. Right now the package is loaded every time I call the script, which causes some overhead.

Comment: this isn't possible. You could, however, structure your code to run each of the `example.R` scripts as a _function_ in the same R session. Done correctly, when the function exists, your `.GlobalEnv` will be unaffected but the libraries will be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are launching a script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
# do something ...
library(somelibrary)
# do something with somelibrary functions
```

then each instance of it is a new process, a new fresh R process, and so any additional packages have to be attached using `library`. The overhead is unavoidable unless you want to run R as a service.

Comment: @John does that have anything to do with this question?

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem using code restructuring and replaced the bash script with a `python` script and `rpy2`